# Avoid "printf" from printing zeros on empty values

Tags: perl, printf

I wonder how to avoid getting zeros from `printf` when printing an undefined value or empty string with Perl:

```
$ perl -le 'printf "%.4f", undef'
0.0000
```

This little C program tells me that that's the way `printf` works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf ("%.4f\n", "");
}
```

Is there anyway within `printf` to avoid printing zeros?

Comment: C's `printf` is unrelated to Perl's function of the same name. You've used a floating-point field specifier, so whatever value is passed will be evaluated as a number. If you had warnings enabled as you should, then you would get a message telling you about this

Comment: @Mat: The C program doesn't have undefined behavior because `""` is not a `float`. It has undefined behavior because `""` is neither a `double` (which is what `%f` requires) nor a `float` (which would be promoted to `double`).

Comment: @Mat: What's the difference? `float` is a specific type. The three types `float`, `double`, and `long double` are collectively the *floating-point types*, not "float".

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the value to a string according to its contents

This code shows the idea, but it's probably over-elaborate, and can be reduced depending on the expected contents of your variable

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

for my $val ( undef, "", 'XX', 0, 0.3 ) {
    my $sval = defined $val &&  length $val ? sprintf '%.4f', $val : '';
    printf "Value is %s\n", $sval;
}
```

#### output

```
Value is 
Value is 
Argument "XX" isn't numeric in sprintf at E:\Perl\source\012.pl line 7.
Value is 0.0000
Value is 0.0000
Value is 0.3000
```

---

Another way would be to use `looks_like_number` from the core `Scalar::Util` module

This code also handles undefined values by converting them to the string `undef`. Again, the best way to code this will depend on your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

for my $val ( undef, "", 'XX', 0, 0.3 ) {
    my $sval = $val // 'undef';
    $sval = sprintf '%.4f', $sval if looks_like_number($sval);
    printf "Value is %s\n", $sval;
}
```

#### output

```
Value is undef
Value is 
Value is XX
Value is 0.0000
Value is 0.3000
```

Answer (score 3):

The C program tells you nothing. It has undefined behavior, because `""` is not of the correct type for the format string.

You're getting floating-point output because that's what you asked for by using `"%.4f"`.

In Perl, if you print something using `printf "%.4f", ...`, it will treat the argument as a real number and format it accordingly. The special value `undef` is apparently treated as `0.0` in this context. If you want to print the empty string (or, equivalently, print nothing) for an `undef` argument, then you need to use a different format string -- or just not call `printf` at all.

```
if (defined $foo) {
    printf "%.4f", $foo;
}
```

Note that this only checks whether `$foo` is defined, not whether it's numeric. If the value of `$foo` is a reference, for example, you'll get a meaningless numeric representation of some memory address.

Comment: I was going to suggest something along the lines of `printf "%.4f", $foo if defined $foo;`  Same idea.